# Get a single row returned with a many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql

I have a `products` table, a `users` table and a `product_user` pivot table. It's set up in the standard many to many way.

I wish to get a product with all of it's users.

So I perform:

```
SELECT * FROM products

LEFT JOIN product_user
ON product_user.product_id=products.id

LEFT JOIN users
ON users.id=product_user.user_id

WHERE users.id = 1
```

I get back multiple rows, all with the same product data, but each row has a different user.

How can I just return a single `product` row with all the user data attached to that row?

Comment: You would have to have a way to concatenate/aggregate the user data into a column. For example, you could concatenate user ID's with a comma.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. Failing that, see `GROUP_CONCAT()`